# MergeSort algorithm with goroutines questions

Tags: go

I am new to Go and I am trying to understand it a bit better, especially talking about goroutines.

I've found a parallel MergeSort algorithm on GitHub and while I am investigating this code, I've got some questions, I want to understand why is it used and is there any way to convert it to other types.

First question, why the channel is used as `struct{}` instead of `int[]` or something else? Is there any way to change that to `int[]` or any other type?

Other question would be, why this algorithm uses `go func()` instead of creating new function for that? Is there a way to implement it with other function and simply writing `go` keyword before?

And the last question, when `default` case is being used?

```
    func MultiMergeSortWithSem(data []int, sem chan struct{}) []int {
    if len(data) < 2 {
        return data
    }

    middle := len(data) / 2

    var waitGroup sync.WaitGroup
    waitGroup.Add(2)

    var leftData []int
    var rightData []int

    select {
    case sem <- struct{}{}:
        go func() {
            leftData = MultiMergeSortWithSem(data[:middle], sem)
            <-sem
            waitGroup.Done()
        }()
    default:
        leftData = SingleMergeSort(data[:middle])
        waitGroup.Done()
    }

    select {
    case sem <- struct{}{}:
        go func() {
            rightData = MultiMergeSortWithSem(data[middle:], sem)
            <-sem
            waitGroup.Done()
        }()
    default:
        rightData = SingleMergeSort(data[middle:])
        waitGroup.Done()
    }

    waitGroup.Wait()
    return Merge(leftData, rightData)
}
```

[Source](https://github.com/hankliu5/go_practices/tree/master/concurrency/mergesort).

Comment: I would say your questions are hard to answer because they are actually very basic. This indicates that you approached Go from a wrong end: you should attempt to gain the basic knowledge and only then attempt dealing with more complex stuff. Please start with [The Go Tour](https://tour.golang.org). (Also note that the lanugage is called just "Go" and nothing else.)

Comment: @kostix I understand that they're simple and basic, actually, I've figured out second and third questions, but I still want to know the answer of the first one, since I am not sure if I understand perfectly the use of `struct{}` here, does the data goes something like this: { 1 8 2 } { 4 3 6 } and so on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First question, why the channel is used as struct{} instead of int[]
>   or something else?

`struct{}` is often used as a type with channels when the actual type doesn't matter but instead the writing and reading from the channel do. So if you just need orchestration for some form of control, then `sturct{}` is a solid choice as the data being passed can't possibly be useful.